# Space-between elements (inline-flexbox css) does not actually apply

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

This is what I would like (my mockup):
[image]

This is what it looks like:
[image: what it looks like]

I am using React (but that should not matter, all that matters is the main page's (S)CSS which displays all the components.)

**The HTML (it is react so className means class, and all the funky props are for the components only, they don't affect the layout):**

```html
<div className="mainContent">
            <SNavbar />
            <div className="content">
                <Title
                    title="Hey, welcome back"
                    subtitle="Some quick actions for you:"
                    name="Henry Sargeant"
                />

                <div className="cardLinks">
                    <CardLink
                        text="Lookup a Pupil"
                        link="#"
                        svgAltText="Lookup Pupil Image"
                        svg="lookupPupilCard"
                    />
                    <CardLink
                        text="Manage Admins"
                        link="#"
                        svgAltText="Manage Admins Image"
                        svg="manageAdminsBlack"
                    />
                    <CardLink
                        text="Manage Users"
                        link="#"
                        svgAltText="Manage Users Image"
                        svg="manageUsersBlack"
                    />
                    <CardLink
                        text="Lookup a Pupil"
                        link="#"
                        svgAltText="Lookup a Pupil Image"
                        svg="lookupPupilsBlack"
                    />
                    <CardLink
                        text="View Error Logs"
                        link="#"
                        svgAltText="View Error Logs Image"
                        svg="warnBlack"
                    />
                </div>

                <div className="userStats-container">
                    <UserStats />
                    <CurrentAdmins admins={adminList} />
                    <StaffMembers staff={staff} />
                </div>

                <div className="switchstaffbtn">
                    <SwitchButton />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

My (S)CSS:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');

* {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Poppins';
    font-weight: normal;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    -ms-overflow-style: none;
    scrollbar-width: none;
}

*::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}

.mainContent {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.cardLinks {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 50vw;
    margin-left: 2em;
    margin-top: 2em;
}

.userStats-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-around;
    margin-top: 80px;
}
```

Thanks for your help,
Henry.

Comment: Ideally for a problem like this you'd show a simple bit of rendered HTML and the relevant CSS. Without a demo it's tough to be confident in any answers.

Answer (score 1):

`justify-content: space-between;` ?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/29946367)

Comment: I didn't try to critique his code. I was trying to suggest that
`justify-content: space-between;` + `display: flex` on the wrapper element should fix his issue. 
I don't know the generated markup in this case so it's hard to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the mainContent div has a width of 100vw. Currently, mainContent div is only as wide as the elements within it; therefore, the elements cannot space apart any more because they are already taking up the entire container. We need to define a width on mainContent.

```
.mainContent {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 100vw;
}

.userStats-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 80px;
}
```

Also, it will be good to align-items: center; (vertically) on userStats-container